# How to sync a postgres database in local network with a postgres database in global network without providing public ip for local database?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a postgres database that is installed on the local network with no public ip address and a postgres database in the cloud that has a public ip address.

The existing system includes copying all the changes into a csv file from the local database, and then connecting the cloud database in the local database using foreign data wrappers (which basically lets you have tables from other databases inside another database as foreign tables). Using this foreign table, I execute the query to truncate a table and import the data from the csv file.

I have looked into postgres replication using wal files, but this requires the host (in my case the local database) to have a public ip address so that the client server that receives the data can connect to the host to look up the wal files. (WAL files are write ahead log files that postgres keep every time there is a change made to the database)

Is it possible to sync tables in local database to cloud database from local database?

Comment: No, and replication won't synchronize two databases. Stick with your current solution.

Comment: You could try to run [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) on your local network that pushes changes to the public server